# filter objects by multiple dropdowns

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, html-select, visibility

I have a lot of buttons, each with three classes. The first class could be "a1", "a2" or "a3". The second class could be "b1", "b2" or "b3". Same for the third class with "c". For example:

```
<body>
 <button type="button" class="a1 b3 c3">Button 1</button>
 <button type="button" class="a1 b3 c1">Button 2</button>
 <button type="button" class="a2 b2 c2">Button 3</button>
 <button type="button" class="a3 b1 c3">Button 4</button>
</body>
```

What i want to do is to filter these buttons by make them only visible when the fitting classes are selected in a dropdown menu for each kind of class:

```
 <select name="a"> 
    <option>all</option> 
    <option>a1</option> 
    <option>a2</option>
    <option>a3</option>
 </select>

 <select name="b"> 
    <option>all</option> 
    <option>b1</option> 
    <option>b2</option>
    <option>b3</option>
 </select>

 <select name="c">
    <option>all</option> 
    <option>c1</option> 
    <option>c2</option>
    <option>c3</option>
 </select>
```

For example: If in the dropdown menu a "a1" and in b "b3" and in c "all" is selected, Button 1 and Button 2 should be visible.
Another Point would be, that if in dropdown menu a "a1" selected is, in the menu b should only "all" and "b3" visible.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What have you tried so far? Use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) for that.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I didn't found a fitting solution so far, so i didn't tried anything. I havn't worked with javascript and hoped there would be an html / css option for that. So i guess i have to take a look at javascript now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. So I added a group-class to each button so it would be easier to select a certain group. If you want to leave the group classes, you need another algorithm for `all` filter.

But here is a possible solution:

```js
// Define default filters
const filters = {
  a: 'all',
  b: 'all',
  c: 'all',
};

function filterButtons() {
  // Hide all buttons for now
  setDisplay( document.querySelectorAll( 'button' ), 'none' );
  
  // Iterate over filters
  Object.keys( filters ).forEach( key => {
    const className = filters[ key ];
    // Determine to show all buttons of a certain group or just a certain class
    let selector = className === 'all' ? key : className;
    setDisplay( document.querySelectorAll( `.${ selector }` ), 'inline' );
  } );
}

// Helper function to set display style on a HTMLCollection
function setDisplay( collection, display ) {
  [ ...collection ].forEach( button => button.style.display = display );
}

// Adding eventListeners so we recognize changes
[ ...document.querySelectorAll( 'select' ) ].forEach( selector => {
  selector.addEventListener( 'change', ( event ) => {
    // Set filters on dropdown change
    filters[ event.target.name ] = event.target.value;
    // Filter buttons on change
    filterButtons();
  } );
} );
```

```html
<div>
  <select name="a"> 
    <option>all</option> 
    <option>a1</option> 
    <option>a2</option>
    <option>a3</option>
  </select>

  <select name="b"> 
    <option>all</option> 
    <option>b1</option> 
    <option>b2</option>
    <option>b3</option>
  </select>

  <select name="c">
    <option>all</option> 
    <option>c1</option> 
    <option>c2</option>
    <option>c3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <!-- I added the base class so it would be easier to select all of a certain group -->
  <button type="button" class="a b c a1 b3 c3">Button 1</button>
  <button type="button" class="a b c a1 b3 c1">Button 2</button>
  <button type="button" class="a b c a2 b2 c2">Button 3</button>
  <button type="button" class="a b c a3 b1 c3">Button 4</button>
</div>
```

Comment: ok thanks dude, that helped me a lot! Maybe i expressed me wrong, i wanted an and condition instead of an or condition between the filters. For example if "a2", "b3" and "c3" is selected, nothing should show up because no button has these three classes